# SMTP email using gmail sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, smtp

I try to make an email service in my project using **Gmail SMTP**,
but when the Socket connection start I get this error:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.233.166.109:25"

This is a part of the code:

```
private static string SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";

private enum SMTPResponse : int
{
    CONNECT_SUCCESS = 220,  
    GENERIC_SUCCESS = 250,
    DATA_SUCCESS = 354,
    QUIT_SUCCESS = 221
}

public static bool Send(MailMessage message)
{
    IPHostEntry IPhst = Dns.GetHostEntry(SmtpServer);
    IPEndPoint endPt = new IPEndPoint(IPhst.AddressList[0], 25);
    Socket s = new Socket(endPt.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    s.Connect(endPt);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to send email using sockets rather than `SmtpClient`?

Comment: Gmail doesn't use port 25 which is non-secure email.  Check the documentation at GMAIL website to get exact SMTP format.  Make sure the FROM email address and the Credentials use the same email account.

Comment: @mjwills Actually I am new to this and I use this
https://codesnipets.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/smtp-email-using-sockets-system-web-mail/
as a guide

Comment: Thanks @jdweng
I will check this out

Comment: `.NET Framework 4.0 has new property called SMTPClient.Dispose() to fix the issue` That article explains that it is basically pointless to do it that way if you are on 4.0 onwards. You should not follow that article.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try port 587 instead of port 25.

Port 25 is for smtp server to smtp server smtp communication.
Port 587 is for client to server smtp communication.

Outgoing connections to port 25 are frequently blocked to stop **outgoing** spam.
Connections to port 587 require some kind of authentication.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent